# Create token to authenticate in RP application

Tags: token, wif, saml

I've created some model of authentication in Sharepoint. I would like to know from You is it good approach.

We have some IDP which sends in POST SAML token in version 2.0 but RP application doesn't support SAML in that version but in v1.1.

I created for this such model:

1. IDP sends SAML 2.0 to SAMLHandler.aspx page
2. SAMLHandler.aspx validates token in SAML 2.0 (signature) and retrieve a collection of claims from it
3. Based on set of claims I create SAML token in v1.1 supported by Sharepoint and this token is signed by some certificate with password (this certificate is added to Sharepoint Manage Trust store).
4. This SAML token v1.1 is packed in WIF message and sends into Sharepoint which recognize claims and finally user is authenticated
   Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

You may use solution like ACS (Azure control service) instead of SAMLHandler.aspx, in result you will have ability to handle more than one IDP and ever create single sign-on.

Basically your solution looks well, but re-inverting existing things.

Comment: Ok, but I have to use IDP authorization page but earlier when I want to get access to that authorization page I have to send in POST SAMLRequest with signature and then IDP verify me and give me an access to this page. After that this IDP give me SAMLResponse which I will handle by SAMLHandler.aspx so ACS I think in this case is not ok?

Comment: So IDP proxy is that handler and I am using Sharepoint's STS for user authorization process, so my ISSUER now is not original IDP which sent SAMLResponse but Sharepoint which where I create SAML 1.1 right?

Comment: Anybody know is it well approach and it can be solved like I described above? Thanx for any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at Security Token Service. It can be used to exchange one security token with another security token. In your case, you need to exchange SAML 2.0 token with SAML 1.1 token. Security Token Service also supports token verification and token signing.

Comment: Ok, but STS in Sharepoint in this case must sign that token and not any external IDP, because SAMLHandler.aspx is added to IIS where Sharepoint instance exists. Finally this handler translate from SAML 2.0 to SAML 1.1 and sign this token any certificate? So my question is, should I use any right certificate in SAML 1.1 or it doesn't matter so this  SAMLHandler works here like IDP proxy or sth like that. Thanx for any info